# I can't use LiveCharts library datatype property more than once

Tags: c#, wpf, livecharts

I'm using c#, wpf, livecharts and MVVM light.

1. ViewModel Class A calls two method in another class B like

   ```
       FocusValues = ClassB.MethodA(focusDataName, focusDate);
       // some codes.
       ReferenceValues = ClassB.MethodB(focusDataName, focusDate);
   ```

class B is using like this.

```
using LiveCharts;
using LiveCharts.Defaults;
using LiveCharts.Wpf;
using LiveCharts.Helpers;
```

Method in Class B is like

```
   public LiveCharts.ChartValues<LiveCharts.Defaults.ObservableValue> MethodA(string focusDataName, DateTime focusDate)
    {
        List<LiveCharts.Defaults.ObservableValue> returnValues = new List<LiveCharts.Defaults.ObservableValue>();

        // some codes

        for (int idx = 0; idx < tmpDT.Rows.Count; idx++)
        {
            returnValues.Add(new LiveCharts.Defaults.ObservableValue(Convert.ToDouble(tmpDT.Rows[idx][columnIndex])));
        }

        return returnValues
    }

   public LiveCharts.ChartValues<LiveCharts.Defaults.ObservableValue> MethodB(string focusDataName, DateTime focusDate)
    {
        List<LiveCharts.Defaults.ObservableValue> returnValues = new List<LiveCharts.Defaults.ObservableValue>();

        // some codes

        for (int idx = 0; idx < tmpDT.Rows.Count; idx++)
        {
            returnValues.Add(new LiveCharts.Defaults.ObservableValue(Convert.ToDouble(tmpDT.Rows[idx][columnIndex])));
        }

        return returnValues
    }
```

And here is a problem.

When I call one of these methodA and methodB, it works. But when I call both,
last method can't find livechart library. it can't find chartvalues, observablevalue.

the error is like 'Debugger can't find sourcefile c:\Users\btord\Documents\Projects\LiveCharts\Core40\Defaults\ObservableValue.cs'

But there is no such directories. And the file is in another directory.
E:\Personal\ReferenceData\livechart\Live-Charts\Core40\Defaults

Do I don't know proper usage? or what do I need to change?
I know is not effective to use almost same code multiple times, But I'll arrange them after test is done. So I think it is not a good solution now.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there an error message? Can you describe what you see on the screen when the last method “can’t find livechart library”?

Comment: When I try to debug, explorer window pops up and try to find ChartValues.cs and  ObservableValue.cs

Comment: This window is all about the fact that VS can't find sources of `ObservableValue` to show you where exception is thrown. Close this window and you will get your actual exception.